# Logging secrets in the user agent (browser)

Tags: web-browser, logging, client-side, token

There are sound reasons not to put any secrets, PII or other sensitive information into the logs on the server side (see [OWASP ASVS V7](https://owasp.org/www-pdf-archive/OWASP_Application_Security_Verification_Standard_4.0-en.pdf)).

But should the same rule apply on the client side? Is there a sound reason we should prohibit devs from logging e.g. jwt tokens into the console in the browser?

Answer (score 5):

I see no real problem with doing this in development environments. However, I am not sure I would do it in production for a number of reasons:

- Why log stuff to the console in production at all? It just looks messy, imho.
- If you take a screenshot with the console open and publish you might accidentally expose sensitive information.
- It opens up to social engineering attacks (similar to self-XSS) where users are tricked to expose information from the console. Most browsers have big warnings to users in the console nowadays, but I am not sure how effective they would be agasint this.